# How do I teleport to the nearest block of a specific type?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've build a castle, but I can't seem to remember where it was.
However, I do remember there was a [Redstone Lamp](https://minecraft.wiki/w/wiki/Redstone_Lamp) in it and nowhere else in the world.

**Q. I was wondering, is there any way I could teleport to the closest block of a specific type? (In this case, a Redstone Lamp)**